# Validate DNA in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, regex, bioinformatics

I am iterating over DNA sequences pulling out chunks of 5-15 bases at a time into C++ std::string objects.  Occasionally, my string will contain a non ATCG base, and I want to take an action when this happens.  For example, I might see:

```
CTACGGTACGRCTA
```

Because there is an 'R', I want to recognize this case.  I am familiar with regex, but people seem to recommend several different libraries.  I've seen Boost, TR1, and others.  Can someone please suggest either a different way to catch my cases or tell me which library I should use and why?

Thanks

Comment: For those of us who are DNA ignorant, can you specify what, exactly is valid, and what is invalid?

Comment: So, all you want is just to weed out those inputs that have characters other than A,T,C,or G? If so, you can just loop over the string and test each character.

Comment: @ridgerunner, any character other than `C`, `G`, `A` and `T` are invalid.

Comment: The characters must be uppercase? no `a` or `c` ...

Comment: Thanks for comments.  To answer, I have already converted my sequence to uppercase, and only ATCG are valid bases (in this program).  So Harpyon is correct that any char other than C, G, A, and T are invalid. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A regular expression is overkill for this.  You can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of).

Comment: It's there, just look in the right place: http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: @rubenvb Apparently today is not my day …

Answer (score 8):

Using C [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html) comes to mind.

```
if (strspn(dnasequence, "ATCG") < strlen(dnasequence)) {
    /* bad character found */
}
```

Comment: @Konrad: even K&R (pre ANSI C89) describes `strspn` (I checked the C99 standard before posting ... and the book after your comment). What's nonstandard about it? ?!?!?!

Comment: Yes.  strspn is works well, and is cool.  I suggest as the info is in a std::string, maybe a std::string function be preferred.

Comment: @EvilTeach OP has tagged C *and* C++, so answers in either would be valid as the question stands.

Comment: Ah yep.  I had keyed on the std::string.

Answer (score 5):

You can of course use regular expressions. But why not keep it simple?

```
bool is_valid_base(char base) {
    switch (std::toupper(base)) {
        case 'A': case 'C': case 'G': case 'T': return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}

bool is_valid_dna(std::string sequence) {
    for (std::string::const_iterator i = sequence.begin(), end = sequence.end();
            i != end; ++i)
        if (not is_valid_base(*i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a regex to solve this problem, here is one that checks for one invalid char:

```
[^CGAT]
```

Or here is a regex to validate an entire sequence:

```
^[CGAT]+$
```

Pretty simple.

**Edit:** Removed irrelevant material.

Answer (score 0):

Does R represent a potential DNA pair ('letter')? 
If so, the ordering of base pairs is critical in order to correctly display or accurately interpret the entire sequence as a whole.

In a codon. Determine in which place the R is in?  RAA, ARA, AAR, knowing this is very important. Then handle these by defining their attributes.

If its just junk or left over data from perhaps data storage. Loop through and remove.